# Counting inversions of random elements in coxeter groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, coxeter-groups, permutation-cycles

I am trying to find a general interperetation to the following facts (pls be patient to read it).

1. Let's look at the property of [Kendall-Mann numbers](http://oeis.org/A000140) $M(n)$ which are row maxima of Triangle of Mahonian numbers $T(n,k)$ (the number of permutations of {1..n} with k inversions).
   According to Richard Stanley $$ \left| P\left( \frac{\mathrm{inv}(\pi)-\frac 12{n\choose 2}}{\sqrt{n(n-1)(2n+5)/72}}\leq x\right)-\Phi(x)\right| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}, $$
   where $\Phi(x)$ denotes the standard normal distribution. From this it is immediate that $M(n+1)/M(n)=n-\frac 12+o(1)$
2. Looking at combinatorial proof for the property of Kendall-Mann numbers numbers at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73962/a-combinatorial-proof-for-the-property-of-km-numbers)
   $M(n) \approx c n!/n^{3/2}$ and
   $$\frac{M(n+1)}{M(n)} \approx \frac{(n+1)(n+1)^{-3/2}}{n^{-3/2}} = n (1+1/n)^{-1/2}  \approx n-1/2.$$
   This is pretty the same result as #1.
3. Reading through  [Counting inversions and descents of random elements in finite Coxeter groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01389.pdf) I noticed Corollary 3.2 (page 6 of the article) that mean and variance of  W-Mahonian distribution depend on the types of groups, i.e. $A_n$, $B_n$, $D_n$. By and large it's about  $n^{3/2}$ like for #1 and #2.

This results in the similar 'structure': $\approx n-1/2$ .

So I wonder why? I am looking for a general explanation to the facts.
I guess this is due to Cayley theorem but I need a more detailed explanation.